# /browse handler (velocity UI) not initiating CustomQueryParser

Tags: solr, velocity, query-parser

I have defined my CustomQueryParser in my RequestHandler.

Below is the RequestHandler part of the code in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="defType">customparser</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

      <str name="qf">body_txt manu2</str>
      <str name="q.op">AND</str>
      <!-- <str name="mm">100%</str> -->


    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

And below is the queryParser part of the code in solrconfig.xml

```
<queryParser name="customparser" class="com.mycompany.lucene.search.QueryParserPlugin"/>
```

I have ensured that the jar file associated to the QueryParserPlugin is loading.

But when I make a query the correct documents are not reflecting.

Is there a way I can print from within my CustomQueryParser jar to the solr.log to know if it is being invoked?

Also how do i get this to work?

Have been struggling with this since quite a few days. Please Help !

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `/browse` definition is the only one present? The Velocity UI is (as far as I remember, this may be wrong) an output writer with certain properties - I can't see those in your requestHandler definition. Does the network tab in your browser's devtools show anything useful? Which version of Solr?

Comment: No I have other requesthandler definitions, but i have mentioned my defType in /browse handler.                                                                 Also when I check this url http://localhost:8983/solr/tutorial3/config/params          I get the below output which shows the velocity writer has been confiured.                    No, the network tab doesnt show anything. I am using Solr7.2.1  Why is my defType=customparser not being called?

Comment: The output of the config url hit {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":14},
  "response":{
    "znodeVersion":0,
    "params":{
      "query":{
        "defType":"edismax",
        "q.alt":"*:*",
        "rows":"10",
        "fl":"*,score",
        "":{"v":0}},
      "facets":{
        "facet":"on",
        "facet.mincount":"1",
        "facet.field":"manu2",
        "facet.query":"body_txt:test",
        "":{"v":6}},
      "velocity":{
        "wt":"velocity",
        "v.template":"browse",
        "v.layout":"layout",
        "":{"v":0}}}}}

Comment: My point was that you should make sure that this is the only requestHandler that have `/browse` as its path, so that you're sure you're editing the definition you're reloading. I'm not familiar with the Velocity response writer, but I'm guessing there might be a network request in the background to fetch more results as well? Have you checked the `network` tab of your browser's development tools?

Comment: Yes there is only one handler by the name /browse. The networks tab is not showing anything useful